# Multi SQL table update with listview items

Tags: c#, sql, listview

I have a SQL table1 that contains itemcode - itemcount - tablename
and my windows form1 contains listview1 and button1.

When I click on button1 all listview1 SubItems[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcrAn.png) values in the column should update from the tables names in SubItems[2] values where itemcode values are SubItems[0].

I tried the following code but didn't work it as it should, as it only did what it has to do with the first row only not the rest of the rows in listview1:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    item.Selected = true;
}
if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) cn.Open();
cm = new SqlCommand();
cm.Connection = cn;

ListViewItem lvi1 = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
string tableName = lvi1.SubItems[2].Text;
string itemcode1 = lvi1.SubItems[0].Text;
string itemcode2 = lvi1.SubItems[1].Text;

string sql = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET [itemcount]= " + itemcode2 + " WHERE [itemcode]= " + itemcode1 + " AND [itemcount] IS NOT NULL";
cm.CommandText = sql;
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

here are screenshots :

my 3 tables are identical
when user click button " save " it minus all values in blue highlighted column with the value already in their tables in black highlighted column where itemcode = red highlighted column as below :

[listview1 and it's values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcrAn.png)

1- item with code 1 exist in testtbl1 as black highlighted column shows and it's count is 50:

```
testtbl  :  itemcode   itemcount   tablename
               1           50      testtbl1
```

[enter image description here][3]

2- item with code 2 exist in testtbl2 as black highlighted column shows and it's count is 40:

```
testtbl2   itemcode   itemcount   tablename
              2            40      testtbl2
```

[enter image description here][4]

3- now as shown in the first photo the count of itemcode : 1 is 15 and itemcode : 2 count is 20

now when user click save button it should minus the the itemcount of each item in blue highlighted column from the item exists in each item table to give the following result :

[result in testtbl1][5]

```
testtbl    itemcode   itemcount   tablename
              1           35      testtbl1
```

[result in testtbl2][6]

```
testtbl2   itemcode   itemcount   tablename
              2            20      testtbl2
```

Comment: This is very bad and wrong code. 
Firstly you can create command with sql query. You can not set commandText parameters.

Comment: thanks Hüseyin BurakKaradag .. can u correct my code and show me what u mean please

Comment: @HüseyinBurakKaradag yes you can use parameters with commandtext.

Comment: @user5456980 "didn't work" isn't a question. Explain, show errors, etc.

Comment: Whats is it mean SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select bla bla",con); cm.commandText = "update bla bla";  @Crowcoder

Comment: @HüseyinBurakKaradag that was redundant and has been edited out of the question. Its just another way to assign the command and connection.

Comment: Yes i know. I say not use together. if you set command in SqlCommand override methot why can set CommandText ?  Firtly created command object select dml and cant execute then assigned commandText update dml And I just say wtf?

Comment: @Crowcoder  what wrong did I do in this code plz

Comment: @user5456980 You still haven't said what your problem is. But a few tips are: 1. Why loop through listView1 and set each item to selected? You always end up with all or the last selected depending on the list mode. 2. A closed connection is not the only state that can prevent Open(). 3. Commands and Connections are Disposable so you should take care to make sure they are disposed. 4. You don't null check the text boxes. 5. Concatenating parameters like that is a sql injection risk.

Comment: @Crowcoder my problem is that the code does the job as I described but only for the first row and I want it to do the same for all rows exist In listview1

Comment: please show me how to do the right thing in code because i'm stuck for 2 days please

Comment: @user5456980 maybe if you show how you construct the listview and maybe a screenshot. I can't follow your logic about subitems of subitems with subitems. but I suspect you need to put the update in a loop of subitems.

Comment: [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hyOlR.png
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8uDXP.png
  [5]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iemsa.png
  [6]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uZlfU.png

Comment: these are the rest of the screenshots @Crowcoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still find some of your question to be confusing, but I think this is close to what you want. I think you want to run an update for each row, but your were only doing it for the first selected row. If you want to update for each row, then you don't need to bother with `SelectedRows` at all, just loop over them all.
You said you wanted to minus the counts but your query is not doing that, I put that in, I hope it is what you want.
From what I read, `SubItems` begin with the second column (listview index 1) so I have adjusted the SubItems access. Re-adjust if I got that wrong.
Lastly, if the user is allowed to enter free-form text in the ListView then this code presents a SQL injection hazard, so be sure to sanitize the data before plugging the values in the Update statement.

```
string sql = "UPDATE {0} SET [itemcount] = [itemcount] - {1} WHERE [itemcode] = {2} AND [itemcount] IS NOT NULL";
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    string qry = string.Format(sql, item.SubItems[1].Text, item.SubItems[0].Text, item.Text);
    using(cm = new SqlCommand(qry, cn))
    {
       cn.Open();
       cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
       cn.Close();
    }
}
```

## Follow up:

To use parameters change the SQL to:

```
string sql = "UPDATE {0} SET [itemcount] = [itemcount] - @itemcount WHERE [itemcode] = @itemcode AND [itemcount] IS NOT NULL";
```

and add the SqlParameters to the Command (SqlDbTypes assumed):

```
SqlParameter par_ItemCount = new SqlParameter("@itemcount", SqlDbType.Int);
par_ItemCount.Value = int.Parse(item.SubItems[0].Text);
cm.Parameters.Add(par_ItemCount);

SqlParameter par_ItemCode = new SqlParameter("@itemcode", SqlDbType.Int);
par_ItemCode.Value = int.Parse(item.Text);
cm.Parameters.Add(par_ItemCode);
```

However, you still have the issue with the Table Name. You can't use a parameter for a table name. If there is any possible way a user can edit the table name then you must validate it before injecting it into your SQL. This could be as simple as checking it against a list of valid table names.

Comment: thanks for your reply I just have a question .. what should I modify in your code to use parameters instead ?

Answer (score 0):

foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in taskShowListView.Items)
            {

```
            if (itemRow.Selected == true)
            {

                int taskId = Convert.ToInt32(itemRow.SubItems[0].Text);
                string taskDate = itemRow.SubItems[1].ToString();
                string taskDescription = itemRow.SubItems[2].ToString();

                MessageBox.Show("selected");

                ListViewItem listViewItem = new ListViewItem(Convert.ToInt32(taskId[0].Text));
                listViewItem.SubItems.Add(**taskDate[1]**.ToString());
                listViewItem.SubItems.Add(taskDescription[2].ToString());
                taskShowListView.Items.Add(listViewItem);


            }

        }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.